# Receiving Props Before Rendering Component ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I am new to React and I have been having trouble receiving props in a child component on ComponentDidMount. However if I try to render the props, they will.

I need to be able to pass props to child component, and do a few conditional statements to setState of other objects then render it.

There is propbably a way to do this, I just do not know it yet, and all of the questions on here are either outdated or did not work.

Thanks for the help guys!!

Comment: perhaps check conditionally that the prop is precent in the parent component, before mounting it? Not sure I quite understand your question. Could you give some example code as well?

Comment: if you want to add some conditions before rendering the props then just use it inside `shouldComponentUpdate`. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate

Comment: @Viktor what I am doing is passing a date to a child component, and depending on that date, I have to set one of three state objects true, and render the info based on which state object is the true one. hope that helps to explain it.